# TYPO3 Powermail 2 - how change template for plugin instance

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I have Powermail( new version, the one based on Extbase) instance at the bottom of each page. This instance is placed somewhere on the website and rendered in footer via RECORDS.
Now, I need this instance to have different templates than the rest of Powermail plugin instances.

So, how can I pass this configuration to the plugin instance? There is no option in flexform to specify the path to the template so I'm stuck.

Thanks in front ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an extension template on the respective page, and set the templateRootPath accordingly - either by setting the **constants** plugin.tx_powermail_view.templateRootPath or by setting  the **setup** settings plugin.tx_powermail.view.templateRootPath directly:

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
   view {
       templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_powermail.view.templateRootPath}
       partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_powermail.view.partialRootPath}
       layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_powermail.view.layoutRootPath}
   }
}
```

(partials and layout follow the same pattern)

See: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/powermail/2.0.0/view/1/48/

Comment: Well this is just basic - chnage of the template file via TS :)
Not what I asked for it the question. We have TWO instances of the powermail on the same page. We need different template for each of them...

Answer (score 0):

You can set a different layout for this in the "Extended" Tab of the form, as described here:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/Powermail/Faq/Index.html#how-to-change-the-style-selector-with-my-own-values-in-forms-pages

This way a class will be set in the < form >-tag, und you may style the record differently.